# Test if an MSBuild property constains a substring

Tags: msbuild

I have a property in an MSBuild project which is a semicolon-separated-list of string values. How can I test if the list constains a particular value?

In the example listing below, I want the target `DeployToServer` only to be executed if the property `$(DCC_Define)` constains `'WebDeploy'`.

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <DCC_Define>WebDeploy;DEBUG</DCC_Define>
  </PropertyGroup>

   <Target Name="DeployToServer" Condition="$(DCC_Define) constains 'WebDeploy'">
        <Message Text="Do something." />
    </Target>

</Project>
```

I've used a bit of pseudo logic in the @Condition attribute to indicate what I mean. I am using a .NET framework version of 2.0.50727.3655; and MSBuild version of 3.4.30729.1 .

How can I achieve this? I don't have the luxury of being able to upgrade to MSBuild 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since you can't use property function you have to get creative.

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <DCC_Define>WebDeploy;DEBUG;WebDeploy</DCC_Define>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="DeployToServer">
        <CreateItem Include="$(DCC_Define)">
            <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="DCC_Define" />
        </CreateItem>
        <!-- Not required since MSBuild doesn't execute targets twice -->
        <!-- <CreateProperty Value="True" Condition="%(DCC_Define.Identity) == WebDeploy">
            <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="WebDeploy" />
        </CreateProperty> -->
        <CallTarget Targets="_DeployToServer" Condition="%(DCC_Define.Identity) == WebDeploy" />
    </Target>

    <Target Name="_DeployToServer">
        <Message Text="Do something." />
    </Target>
</Project>
```